# How to Add a Dialog/Modal in a Card in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add a Dialog/Modal inside of a Card using Material UI. I want it to look like this:

[image]

The problem is that if a wrap the component `<Card>` around component `<Dialog>`, Card component does not render as part of the Dialog/Modal but next to the button to open Dialog/Modal. And if I add `<Card>` inside `<Dialog>`, Card component renders inside which is not what I what.
What I have tried:

```js
//Card does not render with Dialog
<Card>
  <Digalog>
    Content
  <Digalog/>
<Card/>


//Card renders inside Dialog
<Dialog> 
  <Card>
    Content
  <Card/>
<Dialog/>
```

This is my code:

```js
export default function AddManifestModal(props){
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <CustomButton
        text={'Add Manifest'}
        callback={handleClickOpen}
        style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
      />
      
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email     address here. We will send updates
            occasionally.
          </DialogContentText>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="default">
            Add
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="default">
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      
    </Fragment>
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually mimic the style

```
import { Dialog, DialogContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    borderWidth: "20px",
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
    borderStyle: "solid"
  }
});
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dialog open PaperProps={{ classes: { root: classes.root } }}>
        <DialogContent>Some Content</DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can apply the card styling to your desire.

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-smoke-02pe4?file=/src/App.js:0-610

The reason I suggest this is because, you cannot wrap Dialog with Card or Paper component.

Comment: Thank you very much, this work fine. The only problem now is that i cannot add box-shadow and border radius to the the actual Dialog, that i know of.

Comment: You probably can if you play with the css of DialogContent, but i haven't tried it yet or play with https://material-ui.com/api/modal/